# Wordpress settings menu not displaying correctly

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've create a settings menu with tabs and some content. I get no PHP errors but when I load the page my settings are looking like this:

[image]

So as you can see my content is outside of the tab in the left corner. I'm absolutely not sure whats wrong here. This is my code:

---

Here I register the new menu page:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_settings_submenu' );
function register_settings_submenu() {
    add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'Additional Settings', 'Additional Settings', 'manage_options', 'settings-submenu', 'settings_page' );
}
```

---

This is the regarding function for the add_action above:

```
function settings_page() {
    global $settings_active_tab;

    $settings_active_tab = isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'general'; ?>

    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <?php
        do_action( 'payments_tab' )
        ?>
    </h2>

    <?php

    do_action( 'payments_content' );

}
```

---

This is the function for the tab:

```
add_action( 'payments_tab', 'payments_tab', 1 );
function payments_tab() {
    global $settings_active_tab; ?>
    <a class="nav-tab <?php echo $settings_active_tab === 'payments' || '' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>"
       href="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=settings-submenu&tab=payments' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Zahlungen ', 'woocommerce' ); ?> </a>
    <?php

}
```

---

This is the function for the content:

```
add_action( 'payments_content', 'payments_content' );
function payments_content() {
    global $settings_active_tab;
    if ( '' || 'payments' !== $settings_active_tab ) {
        return;
    } ?>

    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Zahlungen</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <table class="form-table">
                <tbody>
                <?php
                settings_fields( "payments" );
                do_settings_sections( "payment-options" );
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }
```

---

This function gets the content for this tab and init it:

```
add_action( "admin_init", "display_settings_pages_content" );
function display_settings_pages_content() {

    payment_settings_element();
}
```

---

This is the function payment_settings_element:

```
function payment_settings_element() {

    $settings = array(
        'field1' => array(
            'name'     => __( 'Field 1', 'settings' ),
            'id'       => 'wc_tab_field1',
            'type'     => 'text',
            'desc_tip' => __( 'Im a short desc', 'settings' ),
            'desc'     => __( '%', 'settings' )
        ),
        'field2'      => array(
            'name'     => __( 'Field 2', 'settings' ),
            'id'       => 'wc_tab_field2',
            'type'     => 'text',
            'desc_tip' => __( 'Another short desc', 'settings' ),
            'desc'     => __( '$', 'settings' )
        )
    );

    ?>

    <?php
    foreach ( $settings as $key => $setting ) {
        add_settings_field( $key, $setting['name'], createInput( $setting['name'], $setting['id'], $setting['type'], $setting['desc'] ), 'payment-options', 'payments' );
        register_setting( 'payments', $key );
    } ?>

<?php }
```

---

And finally the functions which creates a new settings element:

```
function createInput( $name, $id, $type, $desc ) {
    ?>
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="titledesc">
            <label for="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></label>
        </th>
        <td class="forminp forminp-text">
            <input type="<?php echo $type; ?>" name="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"
                   value="<?php echo get_option( $id ); ?>">
            <span class="description"><?php echo $desc; ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
```

I've absolutely no clue why the inputs are outside of the tab content which has just the table structure but no entries. What do I wrong?

Comment: I cannot see additional settings in admin panel.

Comment: Because he created it. It's not a default WordPress page.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong hook here:

```
add_action( "admin_init", "display_settings_pages_content" );
```

Try this:

```
add_action( "payments_content", "display_settings_pages_content" );
```